# Modifying a date in a subquery slows down execution

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Good day.
There are "rooms" and "meetings" in the database. It is necessary to choose from the database rooms that are free during the specified period. **Some** rooms have a feature - they require a break between "meetings". Information on breaks is contained in another table - "points_settins_types_storage".

"rooms" are in the table "points"

This request is slow (20 sec):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM points p0_ 
LEFT JOIN points_settins_types_storage p1_ ON p0_.id = p1_.point_id 
LEFT JOIN points_settings_types p2_ ON p1_.settings_prop_type_id = p2_.id 
WHERE p0_.parent_id = 1310
AND p0_.type IN ('1')
AND (p2_.id = 1 OR p2_.id IS NULL)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events e3_ WHERE e3_.point_id = p0_.id AND e3_.start_at < DATE_ADD('2019-09-09 20:00:00', INTERVAL (CASE WHEN p1_.value IS NOT NULL THEN p1_.value ELSE 0 END) MINUTE) AND e3_.end_at > DATE_ADD('2019-09-09 18:00:00', INTERVAL (CASE WHEN p1_.value IS NOT NULL THEN p1_.value ELSE 0 END) MINUTE))
```

This request is fast:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM points p0_ 
LEFT JOIN points_settins_types_storage p1_ ON p0_.id = p1_.point_id 
LEFT JOIN points_settings_types p2_ ON p1_.settings_prop_type_id = p2_.id 
WHERE p0_.parent_id = 1310
AND p0_.type IN ('1')
AND (p2_.id = 1 OR p2_.id IS NULL)
AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT e3_.id FROM events e3_ WHERE e3_.point_id = p0_.id AND e3_.start_at < DATE_ADD('2019-09-09 20:00:00', INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND e3_.end_at > DATE_SUB('2019-09-09 18:00:00', INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)))
```

but he certainly doesn’t suit me

please help
excuse me for bad english

Answer (score 0):

how your performance go with last condition modified like :

```
AND p0_.id NOT IN (SELECT e3_.point_id FROM events e3_ WHERE e3_.start_at < DATE_ADD('2019-09-09 20:00:00', INTERVAL (CASE WHEN p1_.value IS NOT NULL THEN p1_.value ELSE 0 END) MINUTE) AND e3_.end_at > DATE_ADD('2019-09-09 18:00:00', INTERVAL (CASE WHEN p1_.value IS NOT NULL THEN p1_.value ELSE 0 END) MINUTE))
```

Comment: unfortunately this option is also slow
I think my problem is using p1_.value in a subquery

Comment: maybe try to join into the subquery breaks info